# issue with counter, javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make a counter that will count(and add up) each second. I'm trying to do it with the timing events but it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            function Time(){
                seconds = setInterval(function(){
                    i++;
                }, 1000);
                return {label:seconds};
            }
            console.log(setTimeout(Time, 1000));
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

it just shows the first iteration and also it starts from 2 instead of 1...

Comment: `SetInterval` will return the ID value that can be used to `clearInterval`. Why are you mapping it to `seconds` ?

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` and `setInterval` return the handle to the timer events as soon as it is called - not the value as you expect.

If you want to retrieve the value you will need to utilise either callbacks, global variables etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution prints the output of `setTimeout`, which is the timeout identifier. This will work:

```
var i = 0;
function Time()
{
    i ++; 
    console.log(i);
}
setInterval( Time, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're only logging the result value of the first call to your `Time` method. Additionally you're assigning `seconds`to the return value of `setInterval` which returns an id.

If you want to return a value each second, update your code to:

```
var _seconds = 0;
function Time(callback){
    setInterval(function(){
        callback(++_seconds);
    }, 1000);
 }
 Time(function(seconds){
     console.log(seconds);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout will return the timer id not the return value.Try this

```
setInterval(function () {
    console.log(++i);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, `setInterval` does not returns the value for `seconds` instead it gives the `id`.

You need only `setInterval`:

```js
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var i = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  count.innerHTML = i;
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='count'>--</div>
```

Using `clearInterval`:

```js
var count = document.getElementById('count');
var i = 0;
var id = setInterval(function() {
  count.innerHTML = i;
  i++;
  if (5 < i)
    clearInterval(id);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id='count'>--</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for the helpful input.
i modified the code to what i had in mind:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var i=0;
            function Time(){
                i++;
                console.log(i);
                setTimeout(Time, 1000);
            }
            Time();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```